# Generic/Polymorphic search in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, polymorphism, swift-protocols

Ok, so I'm trying to become a pro with generics, polymorphism, and protocol oriented programming in Swift. I'm slowly piecing all this together and finally have a few generic functions sprinkled through out my networking framework for an App I'm making. My question is, am I doing this right?

Let say I have a User class:

```
public class User {
  public var familyName: String?
  public var givenName: String?
  public internal(set) var userID: String?
  public var color: UIColor? 
}
```

I also have a `UserController` that helps me keep track of assigning random colors to users, keeping track of users across various networking calls, and sorting and filtering. Here is a function I have that lets me search for users by what ever property I have available at the moment:

```
public func getUser<T>(compareValue E: T) -> UEUser? {
    let potentialUsers = self.users.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
        if user.userID == E as? String {
            return true
        }else if user.familyName == E as? String{
            return true
        }else if user.givenName == E as? String{
            return true
        }else if user.color == E as? UIColor{
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    })
    return potentialUsers.first
}
```

Where `self.users` is an Array of users managed by the controller.

This function uses a generic to save me from writing a search function for each property.

I want to know if there is a more polymorphic way to compare the function parameter to the users properties? Also, from a class design perspective can I leverage protocol oriented programing to accomplish generic searches with less code?

Thanks

Comment: Side note: Filtering an array if you only need the first matching element is ineffective. Better use `first(where:)`.

Comment: I'm not too sure I see what problem your `getUser` function solves – when you can just say things like `users.first(where: { $0.familyName == value })`. Also, I strongly suspect that some of your `User`'s properties should be non-optional (does it make sense to have an unnamed user with no ID?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me begin by saying that I understand that you are on an academic exploration exercise to understand generics, but in this particular case there really is no need to use Generics to write the function you've shown.  The same solution could be written:

```
func getUser(compareValue: Any) -> User? {
    return all_users.first(where: { (user: User) -> Bool in
        return user.userID == compareValue as? String ||
            user.familyName == compareValue as? String ||
            user.givenName == compareValue as? String ||
            user.color == compareValue as? UIColor
    })
}
```

Where I simply use the `Any` type as a stand in for the search parameter.

If you insist on a polymorphic solution to compare property values, perhaps this technique will appeal to your academic quest:

```
func compare_property<T>(_ property : T?, _ value : Any) -> Bool where T:Comparable {
    return property == value as? T
}

func compare_property<T>(_ property : T?, _ value : Any) -> Bool where T:NSObject {
    if let prop = property {
        return prop.isEqual(value as? T)
    } else {
        return value == nil
    }
}

var all_users : [User] = []
func getUser(compareValue: Any) -> User? {
    return all_users.first)(where: { (user: User) -> Bool in
        return compare_property(user.userID, compareValue)  ||
        compare_property(user.familyName,compareValue) ||
        compare_property(user.givenName, compareValue) ||
        compare_property(user.color, compareValue)
    })
}
```

In terms of using less code... my solution uses fewer lines of code by leveraging the fact that comparisons are Bool values that can be combined using fundamental operations.  There's no need to say (in essence):

```
if myExpression {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```

This "if" expression evaluates to the same thing as "myExpression" so putting the "if" syntax around it is kind of excessive.

Comment: Thank you @Scott Thompson. So are generics better suited for making calculation's or manipulations rather than just simple comparisons? In the "Generics" section of the Swift guide they create a generic function that can swap two items of anything.

Comment: Generics are good for... well... generic operations.  You can have a list of things whether the things are strings, ints, or something else... so a generic works.  You can count the number of things in the list regardless of what kind of thing you are counting... so that works as a generic function.  When you are comparing things... the types matter a lot.  It doesn't make sense to compare a String against an Int in most cases... that comparison is not a generic operation.  You can create a comparison as I did here, but it does little more than help ensure the two entities are the same type.